# how to send an array in python post data

Tags: python

I am trying to send an array as `postData = {'WIFI_CLONE', 'keyword#2'}` to python post request as follows and running into exception as `too many values to unpack` ?how to fix this?

```
def AddKeywordToProblem(self, problemID=None, keyword = ""):  
     if self._checklogin():
        problemID = '37040553'
        postData = ['WIFI_CLONE', 'keyword#2']
        logger.info(postData)
        r = requests.post(self._baseurl + 'problems/' + problemID + '/keywords',
                          headers=self._headers,data=postData,timeout=DEFAULT_REQUESTS_TIMEOUT)
        if r.status_code != 201:
            logger.warning('Error: Unable to get data. Server came back with:')
            logger.warning(r.text)
            return False
        return r.json()
```

Exception

```
too many values to unpack
```

Comment: `postData` in your code is a list - it should be a dict.

Answer (score 1):

```
requests.post(data=json.dumps(postData))
```

Comment: I tried that but it throws an error `"message":"Invalid Json Array format passed in the request body. Please pass the valid json Array"`

Comment: after change postData to a dict, you need to take the array out from request data first.

Comment: what does that mean?the API expects a request body with an array of Keyword types (string names or IDs)

Comment: postData = ['WIFI_CLONE', 'keyword#2'] requests.post(data=json.dumps(postData))

Comment: You should update your answer with your last comment.